# Symfony2 form dynamic population

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, entity, dynamicform

I have an entity which describe a school and is related to another entity which describe a "Stage" with an association of 1 school -> many Stages.

The school has the following fields (i'll list only relevant fields/methods):

```
namespace A4U\DataBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class StuAnagScuole
{
    .
    .
    .

    private $citta;

    private $provincia;

    private $regione;

    /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="A4U\FormBundle\Entity\Stage", mappedBy="attendedSchool")
    */
    protected $stages;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->stages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

while the Stage entity is like this:

```
namespace A4U\FormBundle\Entity;
class Stage
{
    .
    .
    .
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A4U\DataBundle\Entity\StuAnagScuole", inversedBy="stages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attendedSchool_id", referencedColumnName="idRecord")
     */
    protected $attendedSchool;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I've created a form that allows the user to register for a stage. At some point the user must enter the school he has attended from a list of schools saved in the database.

Since there are more than 7000 schools i must filter them:

1) First the user chooses a region

2) Then he chooses a district

3) Then a City

4) And finally the school

So i thought to add an entity field for each of the "filters" (the first is like that):

```
->add('attendedSchoolRegion', 'entity', array(
    /*
        usando mapped false si dice a simfony che il campo non deve essere scritto
        nell'entità
    */
    'mapped' => false,
    'label' => 'Regione della scuola*',
    'class' => 'A4UDataBundle:StuAnagScuole',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->getRegioni();
        },
    'property' => 'regione',
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'placeholder' => 'Campo di studi'
        )
    ))
```

In the entity repository:

```
/**
 * Get Regioni
 *
 * @return array 
 */
public function getRegioni()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('s0')
    ->from('A4UDataBundle:StuAnagScuole', 's0')
    ->groupBy('s0.regione');

    return $qb;
}
```

So at this point i thought to add a POST_SUBMIT event to the "attendedSchoolRegion" field to dynamically populate the "attendedSchoolDistrict" like that:

```
    $addDistrict = function (FormInterface $form, StuAnagScuole $attendedSchoolRegion)
    {
        //$districts = $attendedSchoolRegion->getProvincie($attendedSchoolRegion);

            $form->add('attendedSchoolDistrict', 'entity', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => 'Provincia della scuola di provenienza*',
            'class' => 'A4UDataBundle:StuAnagScuole',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->getProvincie($attendedSchoolRegion);
                },
            'property' => 'provincia',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                )
            ));

    };

    $builder->get('attendedSchoolRegion')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($addDistrict){
            $attendedSchoolRegion = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $addDistrict($event->getForm()->getParent(), $attendedSchoolRegion);
        }
    );
```

And so on until the school is chosen. At the end of the process i want only the id of the chosen school to be persisted on to the DB under the field attendedSchool.

But i seem to be unable to pass the value from the chosen region to the "getProvincie" method.

here's the error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to A4U\FormBundle\Form\Type\StageType::A4U\FormBundle\Form\Type\{closure}() must be an instance of A4U\DataBundle\Entity\StuAnagScuole, none given...
```

I hope i've been clear enough, thanks for the help.